# Externally determine which test cases fail - Javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I am working on an problem for which i need to detect which test cases fail for any javascript/node.js application, when that application's test suite is run. I need to determine this in a programmatic manner.

[Mocha testsuite output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqKtx.png)

Consider an example of test output above, for this example I would like to write an external javascript script that can tell me which particular test case failed.

Currently the only solution in my mind is; executing `npm test` in a javascript child process and read its output from the stdout stream, parse the output and extract necessary information, something like this.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const child = spawn('npm.cmd',['test']);

line = 0
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`${chalk.bgBlue('line = ' + line)} , data = ${data}`);
  line++;
});
```

However, this would be a very strict approach. I would like a more generic way of going about it, that can work for a variety of test modules(not just mocha).

Help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `state` for every test after the execution into the code. So you can know if the test has been passed or not.

The code you need is quite simple. Something like this:

```js
afterEach(function () {
        const state = this.currentTest.state;
        if (state !== "passed") {
            //Do whatever you want with this value
        }
    });
```

For example, if you want to store into code, which test has been failed, then you can code this:

```js
var testFailed = []
describe('test', function () {

    afterEach(function () {
        const state = this.currentTest.state;
        if (state !== "passed") {
            testFailed.push(this.currentTest.title)
        }
    });

    after(function(){
        console.log(testFailed)
    })

    it('test1', () => {
        assert.equal(1, 1)

    });
    it('test2', () => {
        assert.equal(1, 2)
    });
})
```

And the output will be:

```sh
  test
    √ test1       
    1) test2      
[ 'test2' ]       


  1 passing (15ms)
  1 failing
```

Now you can play with this. You can use the variable to do your work, or even you can create a file or whatever you want to store the info.